# Is there a built in method to protect pages?

Tags: multisite, customization

I'm working on a site that seems to have page protection enabled on it, but I have no idea how it has been implemented. There doesn't appear to be a plugin installed that is doing it, and the `mu-plugins` folder does not contain anything.

I was wondering if this is a built in function of WordPress that needs to be enabled somehow. Could someone please enlighten me?

Here is a screenshot, if it will help, when a new page is being added or edited:
[image]

Comment: This must be related to the theme

Comment: @PieterGoosen had a look at the theme's functions.php file and it doesn't seem to have anything in there that might suggest it is.